# Cannot render blogdown site when using shiny::includeHTML()

Tags: html, r, shiny, hugo, blogdown

I am using blogdown and Hugo to create my personal site and am running into problems when I try to display an HTML files I have stored in the "static" folder. This is an HTML file I created long ago via R markdown and no longer have the .rmd file or data that it was created from. I am trying to use the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935178/how-to-display-another-html-document-in-place-of-a-standard-blog-post#_=_) which involves using the shiny::includeHTML() function within an .rmd to reference another HTML to display.

Here is my blogdown structure with the HTML I want to display in the static/files/ location.

[image]

When I create a new post and try to use the serve site addin with the below I am seeing an "Error in file(con, "r") : Cannot open the connection" error. I am assuming this means it isn't finding the HTML in my static folder but cannot figure out why.

[image]

Comment: it looks like your working directory is `dsobo-blog/` and youre trying to get `files/AirBnb_Prophet.html`, which doesn't exist. Given relation to the WD, you would want `static/files/AirBnb_Prophet.html`

Comment: Tried the path "/static/files/AirBnb_Prophet.html", "static/files/AirBnb_Prophet.html", and the full C:: path and I get the same error.